# Верстка блока, как реализовать?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Здравствуйте, верстаю для себя, учусь. Почти закончил верстать макет, осталась одна секция и я не знаю как ее реализовать. Не нужно писать код и тд, просто опишите словами в какую сторону мне копать. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Где-то я уже это видел...

Comment: Ты не умеешь задавать координаты элементов? http://csshexagon.com/

Comment: Сделать ромбы не проблема. Как это должно  быть расположено в сетке + красная полоса

Comment: Не легче ли сделать это через SVG? Это не сетка, а random

Comment: Где ты эту картинку взял?

Comment: @alex78191 из pdf файла

Comment: @AGS17 где видел?

Comment: @ДмитрийМоисеев а адаптив нужен? Или оно будет всегда одного размера?

Answer (score 1):

Копай в сторону SVG, т.к. по-любому тебе придется это еще и адаптировать, и тогда будет слишком много Media Query (медиа-запросов) в CSS. А SVG можно и JS отлавливать и рисовать.

Answer (score 0):

Применял inkscape

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 584 333">
  <defs
     id="defs2">
    <pattern
       patternTransform="matrix(0.26458333,0,0,0.26458333,-88.476513,24.685248)"
       id="pattern1766"
       xlink:href="#pattern1045" />
    <pattern
       id="pattern1045"
       patternTransform="matrix(0.26458333,0,0,0.26458333,-101.2588,74.780868)"
       height="489.76595"
       width="1000"
       patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <image
         y="5.9813265e-014"
         x="-5.4123372e-015"
         id="image1000"
         xlink:href="https://www.southmountain.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/ready-to-launch.jpg"
         preserveAspectRatio="none"
         height="489.76596"
         width="1000.0001" />
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  <g
     transform="translate(443.02058,60.6779)">
    <g
       transform="translate(-116.37327,53.661006)"
       id="g1780">
      <ellipse
         style="fill:#000000;fill-opacity:0;stroke:#675a60;stroke-width:2;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1;paint-order:markers stroke fill"
         id="path826"
         cx="-234.46106"
         cy="-45.584476"
         rx="7.5595236"
         ry="7.9375" />
      <path
         style="fill:none;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#675a60;stroke-width:1.33699298;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1;paint-order:markers stroke fill"
         id="path849"
         d="m -115.20366,-44.95371 2.73533,-28.509912 26.057968,-11.886091 23.322643,16.62382 -2.735329,28.509912 -26.057972,11.886091 z"
         transform="matrix(1.5598682,-0.1448872,0.15918552,1.4197581,-44.769767,41.48118)" />
      <path
         transform="matrix(1.6306258,-0.15155978,0.16640638,1.4851432,90.36497,66.99781)"
         d="m -115.20366,-44.95371 2.73533,-28.509912 26.057968,-11.886091 23.322643,16.62382 -2.735329,28.509912 -26.057972,11.886091 z"
         id="path851"
         style="fill:none;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#675a60;stroke-width:1.27855361;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1;paint-order:markers stroke fill" />
      <path
         style="fill:none;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#675a60;stroke-width:1.32568717;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1;paint-order:markers stroke fill"
         id="path853"
         d="m -115.20366,-44.95371 2.73533,-28.509912 26.057968,-11.886091 23.322643,16.62382 -2.735329,28.509912 -26.057972,11.886091 z"
         transform="matrix(1.5598682,-0.14736901,0.15918552,1.4440775,123.88807,2.07046)" />
      <path
         style="fill:none;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#675a60;stroke-width:0.84526575;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1;paint-order:markers stroke fill"
         id="path855"
         d="m -115.20366,-44.95371 2.73533,-28.509912 26.057968,-11.886091 23.322643,16.62382 -2.735329,28.509912 -26.057972,11.886091 z"
         transform="matrix(2.4803619,-0.22796833,0.25312249,2.2338751,312.36846,92.16508)" />
      <ellipse
         style="fill:#dc0000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#dc0000;stroke-width:2;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1;paint-order:markers stroke fill"
         id="path828"
         cx="-232.60902"
         cy="-46.684193"
         rx="8.1264868"
         ry="7.3705354" />
      <ellipse
         ry="7.3705354"
         rx="8.1264868"
         cy="-25.819906"
         cx="-106.51612"
         id="ellipse830"
         style="fill:#dc0000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#dc0000;stroke-width:2;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1;paint-order:markers stroke fill" />
      <ellipse
         style="fill:#dc0000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#dc0000;stroke-width:2;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1;paint-order:markers stroke fill"
         id="ellipse832"
         cx="-64.938744"
         cy="-88.941933"
         rx="8.1264868"
         ry="7.3705354" />
      <ellipse
         ry="7.3705354"
         rx="8.1264868"
         cy="-48.800858"
         cx="17.384478"
         id="ellipse834"
         style="fill:#dc0000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#dc0000;stroke-width:2;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1;paint-order:markers stroke fill" />
      <ellipse
         style="fill:#dc0000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#dc0000;stroke-width:2;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1;paint-order:markers stroke fill"
         id="ellipse836"
         cx="79.145782"
         cy="48.33902"
         rx="8.1264868"
         ry="7.3705354" />
      <path
         style="fill:none;stroke:#dc0000;stroke-width:3.98532152;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"
         d="m -238.40734,-44.082336 43.75164,-23.646834 39.91536,19.414888 -0.14829,42.7063501 47.75909,23.9002829 0.0635,-43.135888 41.254547,-20.931581 0.539174,-41.904351 40.636147,-20.767461 41.063679,20.368886 0.07618,40.787414 61.395976,-30.997964 61.484247,31.227272 0.57713,65.171474 -61.287467,30.781638"
         id="path872" />
      <path
         style="fill:url(#pattern1766);fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:4;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1;paint-order:markers stroke fill"
         id="path979"
         d="m -309.03566,118.56098 1.42152,-67.113952 58.83315,-32.325904 57.41162,34.788049 -1.42152,67.113957 -58.83314,32.3259 z"
         transform="matrix(1.0480021,-0.01778236,0.02219792,0.93757749,104.88076,-25.842713)" />
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: с таким же успехом можно было-бы и в фотошопе сделать и в base64 загнать

Comment: ну сделай тогда - я тоже минус поставлю потом и напишу ерунду какую не будь ...

Comment: Nikita, разумная критика должна помогать прогрессу, не стоит ее отвергать. И на ты мы не переходили.

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev  покажиТе мастер класс

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev да и к тому же у меня рейтинг не позволяет не плюсовать не минусовать ...но буду РАД мастер классу